# How to generate quantile forecasts from first differences?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, quantiles, quantile-regression, differencing

Let's say I have a time series and I am taking the first differences and training a model to output the predicted 95% quantiles of these first differences at future time horizons.  If this was just a normal forecast and not a quantile forecast, I could just convert back to my actual forecasted values by cumulating my forecasted values. However if this is a 95% forecast of the first differences, I cannot just cumulate these values to get 95% quantiles of the actuals forecast.  So how would I generate the 95% quantile of the actuals forecast if I have 95% quantiles of the first differences?